Is this a scam?
I made an account with karcof.com so someone could pay me. Once the account was created the sender sent me 41k in BTC. So now I have a balance of 41k on my karcof account. I tried to withdraw it but it said that i have to complete a Bitcoin deposit because it's considered a 3rd party transfer. The security deposit is in the amount of .006 BTC. They said once i make the BTC deposit into my account where the 41k is already at I can then withdraw the money into my account. People are telling me it's a scam, but with my own investigation I'm not sure how it could be a scam. If the BTC is already in my account then I am owner if it correct? Please help it's only $277 dollars but still that's a lot of money when you don't have any. Does it sound legit ?

This is an "advance fee fraud" scam. There is no money in your account at all. Once you pay them the 0.006 BTC fee, they'll find another excuse not to let you withdraw.
